# UUID,Major,Minor settings for iBeacon devices

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I've got a few iBeacon devices from Gimbal which are configurable through a website. I can assign new uuid, major, minor to any iBeacon devices I have. I'm puzzled at how the iBeacon devices know these configuration changed so that they can broadcast? The iBeacon devices can communicate to web server (this seems not make sense at all)?

P.S.: I didn't call any Gimbal API because I set them to iBeacon type.

Can anybody explain this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the identifiers of most iBeacons requires using an app that can talk to the beacon over Bluetooth.  For example, my company's [RadBeacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-tag) devices are easily configured over the air with our [RadBeacon app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/radbeacon/id789301891?mt=8).

The same applies for Gimbal beacons, which have their own app.  It is a little confusing in the Gimbal case because you have both the web site and the app to deal with.  But it is the app that actually makes changes.  See the "Push Configuration to Beacon" section [here.](https://gimbal.com/doc/ios_proximity_ibeacon_quickstart.html#apply_ibeacon_configuration)

Comment: But what make me confused is I never use their app and I even don't use their sdk. Instead I only use the website to make modification.I don't know how it's possible to modify the beacon through website because that means the website will pass data to beacon.

Comment: By the way do you have android library for your devices?

Comment: I do not believe the beacon identifiers can be changed from the website alone.  As you say, it does not make sense because the beacons do not have internet connectivity of their own.  And it contradicts the instructions, too.

Comment: Yes, all Radius Networks beacons are fully supported on Android.  Our SDK is open source, too, so there is never a mystery about what it is doing: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll do more tests.

Comment: I just got the Beacon Manager app from the App Store and on accepting the T&C I get a message "Authorization failed, please try again"