# iBeacon,a very strange thing with the UUID approach?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Apple says, you can not detect `iBeacons` without knowing their `UUID` .
Hence, you must enter the UUID of the device in `initWithProximityUUID:uuid` .

A very strange question should be asked. if you sell a product that uses iBeacon , a personal one, such as `stickNfind`, or `Tile`, how can they pair with your hardware for the first time, if the app dont know the UUID ?

1. one option is to send a paper with its UUID , which is bad,and makes mass production harder.

2.all of their devices has same UUID, which obviously can't be true ,because there will be a mess.

3. they somehow, write `UUID` from the iDevice, to the module, from the air , on first use . So the iPhone creates `UUID`, than program the hardware `UUID` (`TI C2540` chip), which sound strange to me because it will require a very expensive hardware to be added to this chip .

So , what am i missing with this thing of the `UUID` ?

I can see there are many apps to search for iBeacons, how can they do that ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583628/uuid-major-minor-settings-for-ibeacon-devices

Comment: Changing UUID from air requires a very sophisticated hardware ,thats because when you set hardware to act like beacon, you that have to first move it to speak BLE (the c2540 chip) THAN you can change its UUID. In order to let it speak BLE, you need to have another MCU, and that MCU should also get BLE commands .

Comment: Please be a little more polite to people who are just trying to help. I've edited your comment to remove the insults. They were merely pointing out a potential resource.

Comment: That said, with most of the devices I've worked with, the UUID is obtained by the application when the user specifies which device they want to connect to. It assumes that the device you're connecting to is the only unconnected device of that type in the area (like a heart rate meter), and the application reads and stores the UUID for later reconnection. Some of them do print the UUID on paper within the device packaging, though.

Answer (score 0):

Every iBeacon has a factory UUID. 
Usually, all iBeacons from a manufacturer have the same UUID.
For example, all Estimote iBeacons have the UUID B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D.
Depending on manufacturers, provided SDK allow or don't allow UUID customization (most of them don't).

I think apps listing ranged iBeacons use CoreBluetooth instead of CoreLocation. CB allow apps go get all ranged devices, you just have to filter iBeacons.

Comment: BLE let you listen and discover, but never gives you UUID . when you want to pair things for the first time, you must know the UUID

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the question is very important to understand the whole thing, and i have the answer.

The answer is , that Apple thought about it, and gave the the minor and major fields .
So ,you can make a product, when all your UUID's are the same, than the app can look for that UUID, after detection read its major and minor, and save them for later use.
Than, it will only look for these major and minor .